# why does the button not draw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pygame

I do not understand why the button does not draw on the background it worked before
this does not show an error.
here is the code------>
is this code wrong ? is my problem even reproducible? it could be in the code for the button i would appreciate the help

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840,2160))
running = True
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

pygame.display.set_caption("GermanBall")
bg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime\Tan.jpg")
icon = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime\box.png")
button1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime\shirt.png").convert_alpha()
class Button():
        def __init__(self,x,y,image, scale):
            width = image.get_width()
            height = image.get_height()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.topleft = (x,y)
            posmoose = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if self.rect.collidepoint(posmoose):
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                    print("click")
        def draw(self):
            screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
stat = Button(1550,700,button1,0.5) 




pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
stat.draw()
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong in your class: methods `draw`, `intro`, ... should be at the same level as `__init__`. But basically your class is useless since you're not creating any object of the class. You should have something like `my_button = Button(...)` in your code (and outside the class itself).

Also it is good practice to move your class at the top level.

So perhaps you should start from something like that:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((3840,2160))
running = True
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

pygame.display.set_caption("GermanBall")
bg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime\Tan.jpg")
icon = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime\box.png")
button1 = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\tomarj\OneDrive - Tata Advanced Systems Limited\Desktop\War Crime\shirt.png").convert_alpha()

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

class Button():
    def __init__(self,x,y,image, scale):
        ...
    def draw(self):
        ...
    def intro(self):
        ...
    def game(self):
        ...
    def manager():
        ...

my_button = Button(100, 200, button1, 1.0)  # <- create a button
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    my_button.draw()  # <- draw the button
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but even after what you told me to do it doesnt work... by the way i did make a variable "start = Button(x,y,z,q) "

Comment: @vivaantomar Please update your post to see the change.  We cannot guess why it does not work...

Comment: i had backedup my code which worked but now even That code wont wokr here is the code that worked before: ~~~

Comment: i have now updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Your draw function doesn't know what screen is. You should add an argument screen to your draw function, and pass the function call in the main loop the screen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).